# Question about exercise 3-2 from Fields and Galois Theory by J.S. Milne

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is focused on the notation in this exercise. [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8ai.png)

I don't understand what is meant by $\alpha =\sum_{i \in H}\zeta^{i}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of the Galois group, I don't understand what it means to elevate an element of $H$ that are automorphisms to the primitive root of the unit. Is the root evaluating i? or am I getting confused, thanks for the attention

Comment: The exercise seems to be assuming Proposition 5.8 of the text.